# pandas how to add details to csv before writing a data frame

Tags: python, pandas, export-to-csv

I need to write to a csv file that have 3-5 lines(rows) of details about the file, following which 3 rows of blank lines  before I can append to data frame.

Here is how the file looks like. (Note: lines having '#' are comments for demonstration)

```
some details
some more details
some details that were not covered in last two details
#blankline1
#blankline2
#blankline3
A1;B;C  #headers
1231;1241;abc
1232;1242;abd
1233;1243;abe
1234;1244;abf
.
.
.
```

Here is what I've tried so far:

```
import pandas as pd

file_name = 'my_csv_file.csv'

df1 = pd.Dataframe({"some details":})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"some more details":})
df3 = pd.DataFrame({"some details that were not covered in last two details'})
df4 = pd.DataFrame({"\n\n\n\":}) #write 3 blank lines
df5 = pd.DataFrame({"A":[1231 1232 1233 1234]
                    "B":[1241 1242 1243 1244]
                   "headers":[abc abd abe abf] }

df1.to_csv(file_name, sep=';', mode='a', index=False)
df2.to_csv(file_name, sep=';', mode='a', index=False)
df3.to_csv(file_name, sep=';', mode='a', index=False)
df4.to_csv(file_name, sep=';', mode='a', index=False)
df5.to_csv(file_name, sep=';', mode='a', index=False)
```

but this doesn't seem to work. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a string template and leave `{}` to insert the dataframe into. The whole thing becomes more readable. Useful things to do: 1) Use `"""` for multi-line strings and 2) Use comments to remember why you do something.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "A": [1231, 1232, 1233, 1234],
    "B": [1241, 1242, 1243, 1244],
    "C": ['abc', 'abd', 'abe', 'abf']
})

# Setups the template that the client requested with 3-5 rows of information 
# Followed by 3 blank rows and the dataframe
template = """\
some details
some more details
some details that were not covered in last two details



{}"""

with open('test.txt', 'w') as fp:
    fp.write(template.format(df.to_csv(index=False)))
```

test.csv:

```
some details
some more details
some details that were not covered in last two details


A,B,C
1231,1241,abc
1232,1242,abd
1233,1243,abe
1234,1244,abf
```

*Note: Data from user Taras*